# onActivityResult is not halting the program run

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am trying to make the user to enable NFC and Bluetooth before starting the app.
However, when I am using the **startActivityForResult** and **onActivityResult ** it still keeps running.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initBT();
    initNFC();
    StartApp();
}
private void initBT() {
    mBTState = BTModule.GetInstance().initBT(); //trying to get the BT adapter 
    if(mBTState.equals(eBluetoothStatus.BT_DISABLED)){ //if adapter is not enabled
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BTModule.GetAdapter().ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}

private void initNFC(){
    mNFCState = NFCModule.initNFC(getApplicationContext());
    if(mNFCState == eNFCStatus.NFC_NOT_SUPPORTED){
        UIUtils.getInstance().Toast(this, "NFC is not suppoeted for this device");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not suppoeted for this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(mNFCState == eNFCStatus.NFC_DISABLED){
        Intent nfcIntent;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
            nfcIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);  
        }
        else{
        nfcIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        }
        startActivityForResult(nfcIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_NFC);
        UIUtils.getInstance().Toast(this, "Please enable NFC");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is up and running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    else if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_NFC){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs NFC to be enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

    }
}


private void StartApp(){
    Intent nextIntent;

    if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(MainActivity.this).length() == 0)
    {
        nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
    else
    {
        nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    }   
    startActivity(nextIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems that you're expecting execution in the first Activity to pause after `initBT()` is called, until the started Activity returns. This is not what's happening. Starting Activities happens asynchronously. This means that when you call `startActivityForResult()`, that task is queued, and your code will continue to run until paused otherwise. In your case, that is probably after `onCreate()` returns, which means that the `initBT()`, `initNFC()`, and `StartApp()` methods will all have been called by the time the first Activity pauses for the first result.

The solution is to hold off on calling the next method until the previous returns. That is, move the calls to `initNFC()` and `StartApp()` to their appropriate blocks in `onActivityResult()`.